# how can i get the details of {{product.title}} in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

i have a vue js app which get get {{product.title}} and binds it to my route url and get information

this is my json object

```
{
    "status": true,
    "product": {
        "_id": "625672a8370e769a83g3y7",
        "title": "tecno",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum ",
    }
}
```

this is my script tag

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "Product",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      product: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
  
        console.log("the id is :" + this.$route.params.title);
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products/${this.$route.params.id}`, {})
      .then(response => {
           console.log(response);
        this.product = response.data.product;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, 
};
</script>
```

this is the response from  console.log("the id is :" + this.$route.params.title);

```
the id is :tecno
```

this is my route

```
 {path: "/products/:title", name: "Product", component: Product},
```

this is how i go to the title route

```
 <router-link :to="`/products/${product.title}`">
          <img
            :src="product.photo"
            alt="Placeholder image"
          >
        </router-link>
```

it display me this in my url

```
http://localhost:8080/products/tecno
```

but doesn't display the list of products under the id even tho i'm getting the id is :tecno please how can i go about this

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing wrong ID in your API as request params. You need to pass `this.$route.params.title` instead of `this.$route.params.id` as when you are doing the console, you are getting `:techno` from `this.$route.params.title` and you have defined `:title` in your route file.

Have a look at the below code and update it accordingly.

**API block of code:**

```js
axios
  .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products/${this.$route.params.title}`)
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.product = response.data.product;
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: i'm not getting an response

Comment: @chunfee can you post your API response here?

Comment: i'm not getting any response other than                      
 GET http://localhost:5000/api/products/galaxy%20s22 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: If you are getting 500 error in API then there is some issue on server side. Check it on that side. Rest your VueJs code is correct once you done the changes I mentioned